# Converting enumerations to int-like types in haskell

Tags: haskell, enums

I was following the advice on Haskell's Wiki page: [Performance/Data types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Data_types) to improve the performance of my code, but when I changed

```
data Color = Yellow | Red | Green | Blue | Empty deriving (Show, Eq)
```

to

```
newtype Color = Color Int deriving (Eq,Ord,Enum) 
(yellow:red:green:blue:empty:_) = [Color 1 ..]
```

as suggested in the article, GHC says:

```
Can't make a derived instance of `Enum Color':
  `Color' must be an enumeration type
  (an enumeration consists of one or more nullary, non-GADT constructors)
  Try -XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving for GHC's newtype-deriving extension
In the newtype declaration for `Color'
```

I haven't worked with Enums much, how do I turn Color into an Enum type? Do I have to implement all the functions it defines? I thought they were all implemented when you derived that class.

Comment: To quote GHC's message: `Try -XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving for GHC's newtype-deriving extension`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sometimes GHC's advice is bad, but in this case it's spot on.  At the top of your file, put

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
```

`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` is a language extension that allows you to specify that some classes should be "forwarded" to their representation's instances.  That is, `newtype Color = Color Int deriving (Enum)` says to implement `Color`'s `Enum` instance just by using `Int`'s (after some necessary wrapping/unwrapping, which GHC generates for you).

But if this is the only reason you need `Enum`, you could also omit it and just do

```
(yellow:red:green:blue:empty:_) = map Color [1..]
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that by deriving `Enum` you'll get only a partially correct implementation. For example, `enumFrom yellow` will return a list equivalent to `map Color $ [1..]`, which is probably not what you want.

So I'd rather suggest to implement `Enum` together with [`Bounded`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aBounded) manually so that it satisfies [rules given in the documentation of `Enum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aEnum).

I suppose all this stuff could be generated automatically with [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell). This would make an interesting library.